# Php function not returning array values

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for this dumb question, but I really don't see what I'm doing wrong :(

I've this 2 functions within a class

```
function getParentCat($treeTag) 
{

    // fetch some db data
    $parentId = $row->Fparent_id;
    $parentArray = array();

    if ($parentId > 0) {
        $parentArray = $this->iterateParentCat($parentArray,$parentId);

            // print_r here show nothing, no array, nothing !

    }  else {
        $parentArray[] = $treeTag;
    }
    return $parentArray;
}
```

And the second function :

```
function iterateParentCat($parentArray,$parentId)
{
    // Fetch some db data
    $parentArray[] = $row->Ftag;

    if ($row->Fparent_id > 0) {
        $this->iterateParentCat($parentArray,$row->Fparent_id);

    }  else {

         // print_r here show a perfect, beautiful array

        return $parentArray;
    }
}
```

So it seems I've lost the array (not just the content, the whole array) between the 2 functions. It must be a simple thing... but I can't see it ! Soooory :)

Comment: `return $this->iterateParentCat($parentArray,$row->Fparent_id);`?

Comment: Thank you !!! I knew it was something really obvious ! My mind is fogged... a 1000 thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Create reference variable.

```
function getParentCat($treeTag) 
    {

        // fetch some db data
        $parentId = $row->Fparent_id;
        $parentArray = array();

        if ($parentId > 0) {
            $parentArray = $this->iterateParentCat(&$parentArray,$parentId);

                // print_r here show nothing, no array, nothing !

        }  else {
            $parentArray[] = $treeTag;
        }
        return $parentArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursive logic (calling itself to go deeper), but you do nothing with the result you get from it. Every call you go deeper, the `$parentArray` from the one-level-up doesn't exists. So it adds values to the array, returns it, but then the one-upper does nothing with it :)

```
function iterateParentCat($parentId)
{
    // Fetch some db data
    $data = [$row->Ftag];

    if ($row->Fparent_id > 0) {
        $recursiveData = $this->iterateParentCat($row->Fparent_id);
        $data = array_merge($data, $recursiveData); // add the data from one down (and one down (and one down))
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do `iterateParentCat(&$parentArray,$parentId)`, telling php that the while recursive path now worth by reference, they will now will update the same variable. IMO this isn't the way go, by-reference should be avoided if you can as it can make simple thing very complex, very fast.